# How to improve accuracy of CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I want to make a compass application,now I want to ask how can I use `newHeading.magneticHeading` and `CGAffineTransform` to make a `UIImageView`'s one end pointer always points to the North Pole? and how to improve the accuracy?

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
 {
         NSLog(@"New magnetic heading: %f", newHeading.magneticHeading);
         NSLog(@"New true heading: %f", newHeading.trueHeading);
 }
```

Comment: You don't show your transform function at all, so there's no way I can make it more accurate for you.

Comment: What's wrong with CFAffineTransform?  It always seemed to be accurate when I use it.  It is a lot more accurate than the heading from the iPhone compass (magnetometer) sensor.